# What editors support "Inline local variable" refactoring for Dart?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, dart, automated-refactoring

According to http://news.dartlang.org/2012/07/improvements-to-debugger-and-new.html, Dart Editor had an "Inline local variable" refactoring. Since Dart Editor is now unsupported, I'd like to ask what current editors offer it.

I looked at the Dart plugin for Intellij Community Edition and did not find the refactoring there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebStorm 11 and IntelliJ IDEA 15 + Dart plugin have this refactoring.

Comment: Upgrading to Intellij 15 did it.